# Show attachment in Search Content Display Template

Tags: display-template, content-search-web-part, search-content

I'm currently making a display template for my content search query.  I would like to show the attachments but I don't know what code I would use to do this.  Here is my code but I don't have anything for showing attachments can anyone help?

```
<!--#_
    var encodedId = $htmlEncode(ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId() + "_2lines_");

    var linkURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Link URL");
    linkURL.overrideValueRenderer($urlHtmlEncode);
    var iconURL = Srch.ContentBySearch.getIconSourceFromItem(ctx.CurrentItem);

    var line1 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 1");
    var line2 = $getItemValue(ctx, "Line 2");
    line1.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);
    line2.overrideValueRenderer($contentLineText);

    var pictureURL = $getItemValue(ctx, "Picture URL");
    var pictureId = encodedId + "picture";
    var pictureMarkup = Srch.ContentBySearch.getPictureMarkup(pictureURL, 304, 100, ctx.CurrentItem, "cbs-pictureOnTopImg", line1, pictureId);

    var containerId = encodedId + "container";
    var pictureLinkId = encodedId + "pictureLink";
    var pictureId = encodedId + "picture";
    var pictureContainerId = encodedId + "pictureContainer";
    var dataContainerId = encodedId + "dataContainer";
    var line1LinkId = encodedId + "line1Link";
    var line1Id = encodedId + "line1";
    var line2Id = encodedId + "line2";
_#-->   
<li>
  <div class="news-item">
    <figure>
     <div class="cbs-pictureOnTopImageContainer" id="_#= pictureContainerId =#_">
            <a class="cbs-pictureImgLink" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1) =#_" id="_#= pictureLinkId =#_">
                _#= pictureMarkup =#_
            </a>
        </div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/469x300">
      <figcaption>
        <h2>_#= line1 =#_</h2>
        <p>Item Paragraph</p>
        <a class="cbs-Line1Link" href="_#= linkURL =#_" title="_#= $htmlEncode(line1.defaultValueRenderer(line1)) =#_" id="_#= line1LinkId =#_"><span>More</span></a>           
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div><!--/news-item-->   
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a managed metadata property called LinkOfficeChild that contains the attachments of an item.

You can check at http://techmikael.blogspot.ch/2014/04/solution-to-displaying-attachments-for.html